# Files from S3 bucket are not getting listed when i mount s3 bucket to Kubernetes Pod using s3fs

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, s3fs

I am trying to mount Amazon S3 bucket with the Kubernetes pod using the s3fs. I followed this article
https://icicimov.github.io/blog/virtualization/Kubernetes-shared-storage-with-S3-backend/

for setting up the storage using s3fs as a docker image. But I use IAM role instead of using Access Keys and Secret Keys for authenticating with the S3 bucket from Kubernetes Pod. This is what I did

- I created a separate IAM role and IAM policy with the necessary permission to read and write files to the S3 bucket
- I also created a separate docker image with s3fs installed and executing the following command in the docker entrypoint
  `exec /usr/local/bin/s3fs $AWS_S3BUCKET $MNT_POINT -f -o iam_role=${AWS_IAM_ROLE} -o endpoint=${AWS_S3BUCKET_REGION} -o use_cache=/tmp`
- Created K8 deployment scripts with necessary environment variables and deployed the created docker artifacts to the EKS cluster. I also created the K8 ServiceAccount with the IAM role annotations added as well.
- When I deployed the created docker artifact, I can see that pod created successfully and able to see the ServiceAccount token inside the pod.
- But I am not able to see any logs from the Kubernetes pod, whenever I try to access the logs, the pod exits after some time.
- I also tried to get inside the pod and tried running the following

```
/usr/local/bin/s3fs s3-bucket /data -f -o iam_role=IAM_role -o endpoint='us-east-1' -o use_cache=/tmp
```

I got the following message when I run the above command and exits the pod after sometime

[INF] curl.cpp:InitMimeType(438): Loaded mime information from /etc/mime.types
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_init(3304): init v1.88(commit:6d65e30) with OpenSSL

Any suggestion on the issue would be great.

Comment: Did you follow this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html ?

Comment: Yes. I used the mentioned userguide for setting up IAM role for Service account